# No Output in document.write

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a book exercise with this question:

Using document write, write code that displays the results of the 12 times table. Its output should be the results of the calculations: 12 * 1 = 12, 12 * = 24, 12 * 3 = 36 to 12 * 11 = 132, 12 * 12 = 144.

My Code:

```
var loopCounter;
for(loopCounter = 1; loopCounter <= 12; loopCounter++) {
loopCounter * 12;
}
document.write(loopCounter);
```

Why is the output only the number 13?

Comment: Your `document.write ()` is outside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the `document.write` inside of the loop

```
var loopCounter;
for(loopCounter = 1; loopCounter <= 12; loopCounter++) {
  document.write(loopCounter * 12);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string concatenation.

In your case `loopCounter` is the loop variable, whose value at the end of the loop will be 13 that is why it is showing 13

```
var loop = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    loop.push(i + '*' + 12 + '=' + loopCounter * 12);
}
document.write(loop.join());
```

or

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    document.write(i + '*' + 12 + '=' + (loopCounter * 12) + (i == 12 ? '' : ','));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I just need to modify the 2nd solution as it's resultin in NaN but it's working ok now